# Filtrar array de objetos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, es6

Tengo el siguiente array de amigos:

```
friends = [
  {id: 1, name: "uSUARIO2", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 2, name: "uSUARIO2", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 3, name: "uSUARIO3", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 4, name: "uSUARIO4", username: "usuario1"}
];
```

Y este array de followings

```
followings = [
  {id: 1, name: "uSUARIO1", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 2, name: "uSUARIO2", username: "usuario1"},
];
```

Necesito eliminar los elementos del array de amigos que sean iguales al array de following, he realizado varios intentos pero sin éxito todavía. Por ahora tengo:

```
filterFriendsFollowing() {
   let amigos_filtrados = this.friends.filter(
      (friend) => {
        for (let following of this.followings) {
          return following['id'] == friend['id'];
        }
    })
  }
```

Como puedo realizar el filtro correctamente?

Comment: ¿Solo se debe considerar el `id`, o también el resto de propiedades?

Comment: @Davlio solo el Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    filterFriendsFollowing() {
        let amigos_filtrados = this.friends.filter(friend=>{
           let res = this.followings.find((following)=>{
            return following.id == friend.id;
            });
         return res == undefined;
         });
      }
```

Se usa la función filter() en el arreglo friends,eso permitirá crear el arreglo buscado. Dentro de la función filter, se usa la función find() en el arreglo followings. La función find() devuelve la primera ocurrencia del elemento buscado, si no lo encuentra devuelve undefined, en este caso , la condición será following.id == friend.id; luego, para la función filter(), se evalúa la variable res; si es igual a undefined significa que no se encontró el objeto friend dentro del arreglo followings y por lo tanto cumple la condición y se retorna en el nuevo arreglo.

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco su funcionamiento?

Comment: Se usa la función filter() en el arreglo friends,eso permitirá crear el arreglo buscado. Dentro de la función filter,para elemento following, se usa la función find() en el arreglo followings. La función find() devuelve la primera ocurrencia del elemento buscado, si no lo encuentra devuelve undefined, en este caso , la condición será following.id == friend.id; luego, para la función filter(), se evalúa la variable `res`; si es igual a undefined significa que no se encontró el objeto friend dentro del arreglo followings y por lo tanto cumple la condición y se retorna en el nuevo arreglo.

Comment: no me dan reputación, ya debeías de saberlo, así es más facil de ver que buscarlo en los comentarios

Comment: Soy consciente, si hubiera sido yo lo hubiera detectado el sistema, tal vez es un buen tema a tratar en el meta, en que casos modificar la respuesta. Yo pienso que si le ahorra tiempo y esfuerzo a alguien en busca de respuestas vale la pena.

Comment: @Dev.Joel he preguntado en el meta, por favor incluye tu opinión, sería mu importante para mí https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3109/debo-modificar-las-respuestas-de-otros-usuarios

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro no había visto bien el escenario, en esta ocasión creo que si puede editar la respuesta, recién leí el comentario de usuario que respondió. Usted solo paso el comentario a la respuesta . válido para mi gusto, mil disculpas ha sido mi error borré comentarios para limpiar la respuesta, Saludos.

Comment: @crrlos Gracias por la explicacioón, ahora entiendo muy bien. Tu respuesta para mi es la mejor, Es mucho más concisa.

Answer (score 2):

Debería filtrar cuando por cada friendo no hay un following correspondiente. Acá te dejo un snippet un poco más optimo, espero que te sirva:

```js
let friends = [
  {id: 1, name: "uSUARIO2", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 2, name: "uSUARIO2", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 3, name: "uSUARIO3", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 4, name: "uSUARIO4", username: "usuario1"}
];

let followings = [
  {id: 1, name: "uSUARIO1", username: "usuario1"},
  {id: 2, name: "uSUARIO2", username: "usuario1"},
];

let amigos_filtrados = friends.filter(
  (friend) => {
    let ok = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < followings.length && ok; i++) { // Corta cuando no hay mas following o cuando ya se encontró uno
      let following = followings[i];
      if (following['id'] == friend['id'])
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
})

console.log(amigos_filtrados);
```